# TextBox for WP7 limit in text ? bug?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a TextBox, in which I set the content programmatically :

> LegalTextBlock.Text = "Some awfully
>   long legal content";

(see here for a Lorem Ipsum sample that illustrate my problem : http://pastebin.com/jWLrwcGe)

The test is about 4k characteres long, and is not displayed completely. Is this normal ? How could I proceed to display long static text ?

Here is my xaml :

```
            <ScrollViewer Margin="8">
            <TextBlock x:Name="LegalTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not displayed completely"? Also, what's the width and height of the container of the `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: For my 10 paragraphs lorem ispum, only 3 or 4 are displayed. For my actuel legal text, it stops about 3 quarters near the end.. the container of ScrollViewer is the default ContentPanel Grid and has no specified width/height, so it's Auto

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Any element that must be displayed
>   beyond the area which is larger than
>   2048x2048 pixels would be clipped by
>   the platform

Check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx) out, a custom control has been created to deal with the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: this definitely looks like my problem ! I'll check it out thanks (I have to wait a few minutes to accept you're answer)