# TextBlock is Cutting Text in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, textblock

In my WP8 project textblock is cutting text unexpectedly. How can I solve it? I have used VerticalAlignment Strecth or Height auto in scrollviewer but they have not solve it.

[image: Textblock]

And my xaml, I am using one of these stackpanels :

```
 <ScrollViewer>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackNormal" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
                            <ListBox Name="ImageList"  ItemsSource="{Binding Summary.Text , Converter={StaticResource ImageFromRssText}}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding URL}" Tag="{Binding Title}" Margin="5,15,0,0"></Image>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" MouseLeftButtonUp="feedTitle_MouseLeftButtonUp" FontSize="25" Name="feedTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Text="{Binding Title.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,3,0,2" />
                            <TextBlock Name="feedSummary" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,0,15,0" Text="{Binding Summary.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmerLong}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="feedPubDate" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" Margin="12,20,0,5" Text="{Binding PublishDate.DateTime}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPhotoBug" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Transparent">
                            <ListBox Name="ImageList2"  ItemsSource="{Binding Links}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImagesFromRssTextForPhotoBug}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,15,0,0" MaxHeight="500"></Image>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline" MouseLeftButtonUp="feedTitle_MouseLeftButtonUp" FontSize="25" Name="feedTitle2" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Text="{Binding Title.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmer}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,3,0,2" />
                            <TextBlock Name="feedSummary2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5,0,15,0" Text="{Binding Summary.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmerLong}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            <TextBlock Name="feedPubDate2" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}" Margin="12,20,0,5" Text="{Binding PublishDate.DateTime}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is because of such big text (TextBlock has limit - 2048px). You should try [ScrollableTextBlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368670/textbox-for-wp7-limit-in-text-bug)

Answer (score 1):

Place the textblock inside scrollviewer

```
<scrollviewer verticalBarvisibility="visible">
    <TextBlock Name="feedSummary" TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Text="{Binding Summary.Text, Converter={StaticResource RssTextTrimmerLong}}" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="20"
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</scrollviewer>
```

Comment: Textblock not getting scrolled??

Comment: did u give any fixed height or width to the textblock?

Answer (score 1):

Any element that must be displayed beyond the area which is larger than 2048x2048 pixels would be clipped by the platform

[Creating Scrollable TextBlock for WP7.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx)