# Character or text limit in ScrollView or TextBlock?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, text, scrollviewer, textblock

Is there a limit to the amount of data/text that can be stored in a TextBlock/ScrollViewer?

I currently have this:

```
 <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" Margin="0,151,0,0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="auditText" Text="TextBlock" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Height="Auto" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Padding="20" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                </TextBlock>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

It appears to work but as I get further down the scroll I find this:

[image]

As you can see there is more text but it just stops....any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a height specified on the container the scrollviewer is in? Also you have the textblock with a grid attached property not the scrollviewer.

Comment: I guess the height property is making the mess. Where do you have the `ScrollViewer` as jfin asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that any element that must be displayed beyond the area which is larger than 2048x2048 pixels would be clipped by the platform.

You need to divide up your text into segments blocks and display.

[`TextBlock is Cutting Text in Windows Phone`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869532/textblock-is-cutting-text-in-windows-phone)