# windows phone 8 app textBlock hide text c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

[image]

As you see, text hidding in textblock, i don't know what is that. Text always are dinamically, so i can't set fixed size.

My XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="Page" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" UseLayoutRounding="True">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-628,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">       
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="MainContent" UseLayoutRounding="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,42,0,0"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this,

Set the  ScrollViewer Height to "Auto"

```
<ScrollViewer Height="Auto"  Grid.Row="1">
```

If it does not work,There is a 2048 pixel limitation for UI controls. Sometimes the text to be displayed is so large that it can’t fit in a TextBlock and some of it overflows. You could create a scrollable textbox as a solution or You need to divide up your text into multiple blocks to display it all.

[`ScrollableTextBlock`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368670/textbox-for-wp7-limit-in-text-bug)